# Able to create Google Docs but couldn't create Google Sheets

Tags: google-drive-api

I am making a feature in my Java backend to create a Google Sheet.

Now in that backend, it already has a function to create Google Docs and it is working well. Following is the function to create a Google Doc.

```
  public String createFileFromHtml(Project project, String html) throws DocumentGatewayException {
// Determine the google drive ID for the given areaId
String areaId =
    Strings.isNullOrEmpty(project.getAreaId()) ? Constants.TEST_AREA : project.getAreaId();
String areaGoogleDriveId = null;
try {
  if (areaIdToGoogleDriveIdMap.isEmpty() || !areaIdToGoogleDriveIdMap.containsKey(areaId)) {
    String pageToken = null;
    do {
      String query = "'" + ERD_GOOGLE_DRIVE_ID + "' in parents";
      query += " and mimeType = '" + FOLDER_MIME_TYPE + "'";
      query += "and trashed = false";
      FileList result =
          drive
              .files()
              .list()
              .setQ(query)
              .setPageToken(pageToken)
              .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
              .execute();
      for (File file : result.getFiles()) {
        areaIdToGoogleDriveIdMap.put(file.getName(), file.getId());
      }
      pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new DocumentGatewayException(e);
}
areaGoogleDriveId = areaIdToGoogleDriveIdMap.get(areaId);
Preconditions.checkArgument(
    !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(areaGoogleDriveId), areaId + " needs to have a google drive folder");

// Generate metadata to be used to create the file using the google drive ID above.
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName(project.getTitle());
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(areaGoogleDriveId));

try {
  // Create file.
  File file =
      drive
          .files()
          .create(
              fileMetadata,
              new ByteArrayContent("text/html", html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
          .setFields("id")
          .execute();

  // Make all authors writers
  if (!project.getAuthorIds().isEmpty()) {
    for (String authorId : project.getAuthorIds()) {
      processor.setWritter(project.getUuid(), file.getId(), authorId, 0);
    }

    // Set owner
    String authorId = EmailUtils.AuthorNameToEmail(project.getAuthorIds().get(0));
    processor.setOwner(project.getUuid(), file.getId(), authorId, 0);
  }
  // Set commenter
  processor.setCommenter(project.getUuid(), file.getId(), 0);

  return file.getId();
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.error(
      "Error creating document", KeyValue.string("project_uuid", project.getUuid()), e);
  throw new DocumentGatewayException(e);
}
```

}

I wanted to create a Google Sheet instead. So I tried changing `application/vnd.google-apps.document` to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`. But after this change, it was still creating Google Doc instead of Google Sheet.

So anyones knows why? I just need to create a Google Sheet.

Google Drive API version: `google-api-services-drive-v3-rev130-1.25.0`

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask you about the data of `new ByteArrayContent("text/html", html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`? If you want to create new Spreadsheet by converting a file with the mimeType of `text/html`, unfortunately, it cannot be achieved. Because `text/html` is converted to only `application/vnd.google-apps.document` at Drive API. But I'm not sure about the information of the file of `text/html` from your question. So I asked about it.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. I just found the same solution you also mentioned. I changed `text/html` to `text/csv` and it generates Google Sheet now. When the content type is `text/html`, no matter what MIME type it is, it always creates Google Doc. I think Google should output an error if the content type is not supported by the MIME type. Instead, Google automatically change the MIME type supported by the content type.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Can you kindly share the code(if it is possible now) where you are ```creating an empty Google SpreadSheet into a specific folder in GDrive```? I will be grateful. @Zhen